# Lightning Dynamic Controller

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Finishing a drag and drop feature with a list but I came across a difficulty :

Is it possible to add a controller action to a DOM element added dynamically ?

Let's say I have a userController.js, in which I have my functions (such as drop, drag, allowDrop...)

I tried innocently something like this when I'm in my drop function :

`li.setAttribute("ondragstart", "{!c.drag}");`

But when executing the code, I encounter a

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined
```

Which is totally fine, I agree with the compiler ! But how can I implement the action to this li element I add dynamically ?

*Edit* I'll try with an anonymous function .. !

*Edit2* I realize my first try wasn't that good at all..

Thing is I do not see where to declare the action. Not as an attribute ? Not as an anon function ? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: can you wait till the next release? We'll have something helpful for this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. 
I'll be glad to know what is it if you don't mind. Maybe my approach wasn't good in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next release you'll be able to associate controller actions with methods on your component, then you'll be able to reference your controller actions pretty easy.

li.setAttribute("ondragstart", function() { cmp.dragged(); });

You can also get a reference to the li in your cmp
...
function(cmp, event, helper) { 
 cmp.find("li1").set("v.ondrag", helper.ondrag);
}

Comment: It seems like exactly what I need.. Guess I'll have to wait. Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear! :)